# TextBox Truncates Strings at '\0' Character

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encoding, textbox

I have a WinForms application with a multi-line textbox. I'm populating the textbox as follows:

```
TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
```

The problem is that some of the files have binary characters in them, including `'\0'`, and the textbox truncates the text at that point.

I understand the reason for this (internally, the control uses `'\0'` to signal the end of the string); however, I can load these files into Notepad. I thought Notepad uses the very same edit control that the textbox does.

Is there any way to duplicate what Notepad does? These are old .WRI files, which NotePad reports as being loaded using UTF8 if that helps at all.

Comment: How would your text box display a `\0`?

Comment: Preferably the way NotePad does. I don't care if it shows it or hides. I just don't want it to truncate what comes after.

Comment: Why don't you just remove it from the string?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just trying to figure out how NotePad does it. But, now that I think about it, that's probably exactly what NotePad does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filename).Replace("\0", "");
```